# Rails 4 Carrierwave, Amazon S3, Fog error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

Getting this error

Excon::Errors::SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)):

controller

```
def create
  @gamepic = Gamepic.new(gamepic_params)
  if @gamepic.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created picture."
    redirect_to @gamepic.gallery
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Carrierwave Config

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp')
  config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave'
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => '---',                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => '---,                        # required
    :region                 => 'us-west-2',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    :host                   => 's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    :endpoint               => 'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = '---'                     # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Region is correct and directory is too

any idea what might the problem be?

Comment: Did you get the answer for this ? Please update.

Comment: Make sure the bucket region matches the config. See Below

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch from "fog" to ["carrierwave-aws"](https://github.com/sorentwo/carrierwave-aws).
`Excon` is the library that "fog" uses internally for interacting with cloud services. You should not get the same error with "carrierwave-aws".

Answer was made according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029663/carrierwave-exconerrorssocketerror) post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **region in your config** file and the **actual bucket region** match.

```
config.fog_credentials = {
    :region                 => 'us-west-2',                  # optional
  }
```