# carrierwave Excon::Errors::SocketError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave, null

I have read several posts and solutions related to this, but I still cannot figure it out and still returns 
"
Excon::Errors::SocketError at /posts
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)"

this is config/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => '----',                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => '----',                        # required
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    :host                   => 's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    :endpoint               => 'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
   }
   config.fog_directory  = 'name_of_directory'                     # required
   config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
   config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
   config.asset_host     = 'https://assets.example.com'   
 end
```

avatar_upload.rb

```
 # encoding: utf-8

  class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    storage :fog
    process :resize_to_fit => [900,500]

   version :thumb do
      process :resize_to_fill => [200,200]
     end

   def cache_dir
      "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
    end

   def store_dir
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
   end
    def default_url
      #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
      #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
     #
        "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
    end

    def extension_white_list
      %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
    end
  end
```

from post controller

```
 def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)
   @post.user = current_user

    unless current_user.admin?
     unless current_user.manager?
       redirect_to :back, :alert => "acces denied"
     end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
     if @post.save
        params[:photo_attachments]['avatar'].each do |a|
         @photo_attachment = @post.photo_attachments.create!(:avatar => a, :post_id =>@post.id)
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
        else
         format.html { render :new }
         format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
     end
    end
```

updated config/carrierwave.rb after installing carrierwave-aws

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
   config.storage    = :aws
   config.aws_bucket = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
   config.aws_acl    = :public_read
   config.asset_host = 'http://example.com'
   config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365

  config.aws_credentials = {
    access_key_id:     ENV['---'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['---']
  }
end
```

after changing to  storage :aws

```
AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError

Missing Credentials.

Unable to find AWS credentials.  You can configure your AWS credentials
a few different ways:

* Call AWS.config with :access_key_id and :secret_access_key

* Export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to ENV

* On EC2 you can run instances with an IAM instance profile and credentials
  will be auto loaded from the instance metadata service on those
  instances.

 * Call AWS.config with :credential_provider.  A credential provider should
  either include AWS::Core::CredentialProviders::Provider or respond to
  the same public methods.

 = Ruby on Rails

   In a Ruby on Rails application you may also specify your credentials in
  the following ways:

   * Via a config initializer script using any of the methods mentioned above
    (e.g. RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers/aws-sdk.rb).

   * Via a yaml configuration file located at RAILS_ROOT/config/aws.yml.
    This file should be formated like the default RAILS_ROOT/config/database.yml
    file.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possibly because of an implementation with `fog`, perhaps try switching your gem to `carrierwave-aws` and see if it fixes your problems :)

https://github.com/sorentwo/carrierwave-aws

I remember having a similar error and after changing, works fine!

Comment: I have updated config. Now I am getting  "is not a recognized storage provider" error :(

Comment: ohh - you need to place your carrierwave.rb into the initializers section, so instead of it existing at `config/carrierwave.rb` it needs to be in `config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`

Comment: oh sorry!! I have already placed into config/initializers/carrierwave.rb :( do i have to change the name to fog.rb??

Comment: nope, that should work - also make sure that in your `AvatarUploader` you stop the reference to `fog` and put `storage :aws` (or just delete this line entirely since its now set from your initializer)

Comment: now I am getting "Missing Credentials" even though i have provided the key in config :((

Comment: this may be a silly question but I'm assuming above when you wrote `ENV["---"]` its actually a real ENV variable and not 3 dashes yes?

Comment: yes those are real key number! i have uploaded the error in original posting

Comment: okay, last question is what are you using to port your ENV variable over? What version of rails are you using? Are you using a gem like `figaro` with an `application.yml`? For the sake of trying out the code, copy and paste the keys directly in there for now to see if it works. If it does, it is just that you are setting your ENV variables up wrong in development.

Comment: I am using gem 'rails', '4.1.4', and using figaro to port ENV variable. I have tried putting keys directly in application.yml, but still getting the same error :(

Comment: sorry when i mean directly in application.yml, I mean put the keys directly in the initializer (don't use an ENV variable) - obviously bad practice, but just want to rule that out (we can change it back later)

Comment: ACCESS_KEY_ID:     '---'
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '---' yes I did put it like this in application.yml

Comment: right - what I had meant was to put the key directly in the initializer to test for now... but no matter, anyhow your carrierwave initializer should now have   access_key_id:     ENV['ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] - yes? (not '---' as you have above) which would give a nil value

Comment: I know it would be so silly :(( but it says "bucket_name may not be blank" but i have no idea where to find bucket name :(

Comment: Do you have S3_BUCKET_NAME defined in your application.yml?

Comment: no it is not defined in application.yml. I just have no idea where to find or create bucket name :(

Comment: I see - well in order for this to work you will have to create a bucket on amazon s3 ... That's beyond the scope of this question but there are many resources online that show you how to do that. I am convinced it will work when you have defined a bucket name :). Mark accepted if you feel comfortable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and switching to carrierwave-aws worked, I also hadn't attached a policy to my user in S3 so check that if still not working.